# Need help to create a loop to copy and paste data in a certain way

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, copy-paste, loopback, visual-basic

I am struggling with a loop from past 3 days, finally requesting help from the community.

I want to each cell in column M from (input sheet) to output sheet in column BE multiple times based on the rows in sheet3 and then continue to copy the next cell in column M (input sheet) and copy it in output sheet in column BE below the already copied data. This should run till the last  value in column M input sheet. Below is the real scenario i am facing

I have 63 rows (62 + 1 header) with value in column M of input sheet (the number of rows are not constant and should be flexible)
I want to copy the value in cell M2 of the input sheet and then copy in the output sheet in column BE (row 1 is header). The number of times this value should be pasted should be based on the row count in Sheet3 Range B7 until last filled row (in this case I have 4 rows in sheet3 so the value should be pasted 4 times in output sheet). Then it should move to cell M3 in the input sheet and copy it same number of times in the next available row in Column BE of the output sheet.

This way it should copy till the last row in column M of input sheet to the output sheet in col BE, the same number of times as row available in sheet3 B7 onwards.

Result to check would be 62 (cells in input sheet) * 4 (rows in sheets 3 B7 onwards) = 248 (in output sheet column BE)

Thank you very much in advance.

Below is the VBA code i have written but something doesnt seem right in this.

```
Sub Allocation()

'Raw data sheet lets us know how many times to copy, here B6 onwards down
'UBRSplit is the input sheet where we need to copy value from M2 onwards
'Working sheet is the output where the paste is required from BE2 onwards


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Integer
Dim r As Integer

i = Sheets("Raw Data").Range("B5").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Row

For r = 2 To i

Sheets("UBRSplit").Select
    Range("M2").Select
    Selection.Copy


Sheets("Working sheet").Select
Range("BE" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial

Sheets("UBRSplit").Select
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SuperUser. We're not a "please write me a script" kind of service. Can you edit your post and add your current script? Then we can tell you why things are not working and how to improve it.

Comment: @LPChip , thank you for your response. I have edited my original request with the code I am trying.

Comment: "I want to copy the value in cell M2 of the input sheet and then copy in the output sheet in column BE" do you mean: "I want to copy the value in cell M2 of the input sheet and then _paste_ in the output sheet in column BE"?

Answer (score 0):

### Generate Data

**Tips**

- (Use `Option Explicit`).
- Use constants.
- Use variables, especially for objects: workbooks, worksheets, and ranges.
- If you turn it off (`Application.ScreenUpdating = False`), later turn it on (`Application.ScreenUpdating = True`).
- Use `Long` instead of `Integer` for whole numbers.
- If it's a worksheet then use `Worksheets`, not `Sheets`. Qualifying the worksheets will avoid unexpected behavior if another workbook is active (selected) e.g. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("UBRSplit")`.
- `End(xlDown)` may fail you big time if there are less than 2 rows of data (it will 'jump' a million rows). `End(xlUp)` from the bottom-most cell is most often the way to go, but I prefer using the `Find` method with `xlFormulas` which will also 'allow' hidden rows.
- `i` is kind of reserved for counters. Rather use more descriptive variable names e.g. `LastRow`.
- Counting from 1 is kind of preferred. From 1 to 4 or from 2 to 5 is 4 times anyway.
- Don't use `Select` (it's slowing down your code). Rather do e.g. `Sheets("UBRSplit").Range("M2").Copy` and `Sheets("Working sheet").Range("BE" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial`.
- `Next` is ok on its own, but `Next r` is kind of more readable.
- Using arrays will drastically improve performance since only once is written to the worksheet.

**My Choice**

```
Sub GenerateData()

    ' Reps
    Const rName As String = "Raw Data"
    Const rFirst As String = "B7"
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "UBRSplit"
    Const sFirst As String = "M2"
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Working sheet"
    Const dFirst As String = "BE2"
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Attempt to calculate the number of reps (repetitions) ('rCount').
    Dim rCount As Long
    Dim wsrCount As Long
    With wb.Worksheets(rName).Range(rFirst)
        wsrCount = .Worksheet.Rows.Count ' for all worksheets
        Dim rlCell As Range
        Set rlCell = .Resize(wsrCount - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If rlCell Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No data in worksheet '" & rName & "'.", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        rCount = rlCell.Row - .Row + 1
    End With

    ' Attempt to create a reference to the Source Column Range ('srg').
    Dim srg As Range
    With wb.Worksheets(sName).Range(sFirst)
        Dim slCell As Range
        Set slCell = .Resize(wsrCount - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If slCell Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No data in worksheet '" & sName & "'.", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
:       Set srg = .Resize(slCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    ' Write the values from the Source Column Range ('srg')
    ' to the Source Data Array ('sData').
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    Dim sData As Variant
    If srCount = 1 Then
        ReDim sData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): sData(1, 1) = srg.Value
    Else
        sData = srg.Value
    End If
    
    ' Define Destination Data Array ('dData').
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = srCount * rCount
    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To 1)
    
    ' Write the repeating ('rCount') values from the Source Data Array ('sData')
    ' to the Destination Data Array ('dData').
    Dim s As Long, r As Long, d As Long
    For s = 1 To srCount
        For r = 1 To rCount
            d = d + 1
            dData(d, 1) = sData(s, 1)
        Next r
    Next s
    
    ' Write the values from the Destination Data Array ('dData')
    ' to the Destination Column Range and clear the contents below.
    With wb.Worksheets(dName).Range(dFirst)
        .Resize(drCount) = dData
        .Resize(wsrCount - .Row - drCount + 1).Offset(drCount).ClearContents
    End With
        
    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Data successfully generated.", vbInformation, "Generate Data"
        
End Sub
```

**Over-Commented, But More Readable**

```
Sub GenerateDataOverCommented()

    ' Reps
    Const rName As String = "Raw Data" ' Reps Worksheet Name
    Const rFirst As String = "B7" ' Reps First Cell Address
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "UBRSplit" ' Source Worksheet Name
    Const sFirst As String = "M2" ' Source First Cell Address
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Working sheet" ' Destination Worksheet Name
    Const dFirst As String = "BE2" ' Destination First Cell Address
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Attempt to calculate the number of reps (repetitions) ('rCount').
    Dim rws As Worksheet: Set rws = wb.Worksheets(rName)
    Dim wsrCount As Long: wsrCount = rws.Rows.Count ' for all worksheets
    Dim rfCell As Range: Set rfCell = rws.Range(rFirst)
    Dim rlCell As Range
    ' Using 'Find' in the range from the first to the bottom-most cell.
    Set rlCell = rfCell.Resize(wsrCount - rfCell.Row + 1) _
        .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
    If rlCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No data in worksheet '" & rName & "'.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rlCell.Row - rfCell.Row + 1

    ' Attempt to create a reference to the Source Column Range ('srg').
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim sfCell As Range: Set sfCell = sws.Range(sFirst)
    Dim slCell As Range
    ' Using 'Find' in the range from the first to the bottom-most cell.
    Set slCell = sfCell.Resize(wsrCount - sfCell.Row + 1) _
        .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
    If slCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No data in worksheet '" & sName & "'.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range(sfCell, slCell)
    
    ' Write the values from the Source Column Range ('srg')
    ' to the Source Data Array ('sData').
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    Dim sData As Variant
    If srCount = 1 Then
        ReDim sData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): sData(1, 1) = srg.Value
    Else
        sData = srg.Value
    End If
    
    ' Define Destination Data Array ('dData').
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = srCount * rCount
    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To 1)
    
    ' Write the repeating ('rCount') values from the Source Data Array ('sData')
    ' to the Destination Data Array ('dData').
    Dim s As Long, r As Long, d As Long
    For s = 1 To srCount
        For r = 1 To rCount
            d = d + 1
            dData(d, 1) = sData(s, 1)
        Next r
    Next s
    
    ' Create a reference to the Destination Column Range ('drg').
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(dFirst)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(drCount)
    
    ' Write the values from the Destination Data Array ('dData')
    ' to the Destination Column Range ('drg').
    drg.Value = dData
    
    ' Create a reference to the Destination Clear Range ('dcrg'),
    ' the range from one cell below the just written Destination Column Range
    ' ('dws.Cells(dfCell.Row + drCount, dfcell.Column)')
    ' to the bottom-most cell ('dws.Cells(wsrCount, dfcell.Column)')
    ' of the Destination Column.
    Dim dcrg As Range
    Set dcrg = dfCell.Resize(wsrCount - dfCell.Row - drCount + 1) _
        .Offset(drCount)
    
    ' Clear the contents of the cells of the Destination Clear Range.
    dcrg.ClearContents
        
    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Data successfully generated.", vbInformation, "Generate Data"
        
End Sub
```